# Eclipse how to add a line before each System.out.print

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to add control on all my System.out.print statements in all my java files with the help of Eclipse.

I am going to use Eclipse regular expression search and replace.

I want to do the following

case 1: change:

```
System.out.println("this");
```

to:

```
if(PRINT_OUT)
System.out.println("this");
```

case 2: ignore:

```
//System.out.println("that");
```

or

```
////System.out.println("that");
```

with "**System.out.print(.+)**" I can find all the locations of "System.out.print ..."

but I don't know how to handle case 2 and also I don't know how to insert that "**if(PRINT_OUT)**" and insert **as a separate line**.

Please help.

**EDIT:**

we do have logging system. Those System.out.print statements are special extra.

**EDIT 2:**

Answers for this case may be useful for other cases as well.

**EDIT 3:**

Andy has resolved my first question: "^\s*System.out.print".

*Now how to change one line to two lines with a new line?*

**EDIT 4:**

Got the answer:

Replace: `^\s*System.out.print(.+)`

with:   `if(PRINT_OUT)\r\nSystem.out.print$1`

Comment: Why not just replace `System.out.println` with `mySpecialPrintMethod`, in both case 1 and case 2, and then you can update all locations by updating the one method; and the commented cases will work straight away when you uncomment them?

Comment: (The easiest way to avoid case 2 is to search for `^\s*System.out.print`)

Comment: Why don't you use logging and set proper log level instead of using `System.out.println`?

Comment: @AndyTurner, you have helped me the first question, thanks

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer with the help from Andy Tunner:

Replace: `^\s*System.out.print(.+)`

with:  `if(PRINT_OUT)\r\nSystem.out.print$1`